# Want to display the position of the element in array in angular4

Tags: angular, indexof

I want to show the question number from the array, I am not getting what logic should be written to display the question no. Whether it is right or wrong.

In these code, there is an array bg.right which looks for the right answer in bg.attemted (response). And the output should be the question no. (1 or 4)

```
<div *ngFor="let response of bg.attempted; let ic = index"  [ngStyle]="{'display':'inline-block'}">
 <span class="right" *ngIf="bg.right?.indexOf(response) > -1">{{ ic }}</span>
 <span class="wrong" *ngIf="bg.wrong?.indexOf(response) > -1">{{ ic }}</span></div>
```

Comment: Post an exert of bg

Answer (score 0):

as per your explanation this will give you right output, but note here ic is the index in the array so when you print the array it will start to give the index from 0

so to start with question 1 write as below

`<div *ngFor="let response of bg.attempted; let ic = index"  [ngStyle]="{'display':'inline-block'}">
 <span class="right" *ngIf="bg.right?.indexOf(response) !== -1">{{ ic+1 }}</span>
 <span class="wrong" *ngIf="bg.wrong?.indexOf(response) !== -1">{{ ic+1 }}</span></div>`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, But I want to display the actual position eg: arr[1,4,6,7,8]. Suppose I want to display the position of the element 7. Than what logic Should I write to get the exact position?

Comment: welcome, by the way is there any specific property of questionNo. in bg array ?, if questionNo property is there then you should your that property in interpolation instead of index

Comment: arr[1,4,6,7,8]. for this if you want to get the position of 7  which should be 5  in array then above logic is correct